# asking for tips

Tags: discussion

is it oky to ask about tips and some information ( probably should be documented into a wiki) as a question.

For a example a question like this actually not a question but asking for tips.
**How to smartly and politely reject a beer offer in a company party ?**

**How to response to incoming jokes when you reject beer offer?**

Completely asking about tips, same as asking somebody to write a wiki content.
Is it oky asking here?

Comment: It's not a great for for any of the current SE sites. You might want to look at the proposed [Interpersonal Skills Site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills).

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "asking for tips" is actually not a question? How is asking for advice not a question? I also don't know what you mean when you mention asking someone to "write a wiki content".

Answer (score 3):

I think the first question is somewhat on topic, and actually, we have a few questions on the topic already, so it would likely be closed for being a duplicate.

- **[Is there any way to appear sociable at a work social event without
  drinking?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30508/is-there-any-way-to-appear-sociable-at-a-work-social-event-without-drinking)**
- **[How should I handle my manager offering me an unwanted
  drink?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/how-should-i-handle-my-manager-offering-me-an-unwanted-drink)**
- **[Would drinking alcohol (when offered) during a meal that is part of
  an interview be likely to affect the perceptions of the
  interviewer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/would-drinking-alcohol-when-offered-during-a-meal-that-is-part-of-an-interview)**

I'm not sure quite what you mean by saying that this is not actually a question but is instead "asking for tips". Here at The Workplace the majority of our questions are fairly subjective, but that doesn't mean they are opinion-based. See **[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).**

Answer (score 1):

It happens. It isn't always shot down. It really isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange's focus on Answerable Questions. Neither of those is really about the Workplace; the fact that it's a company party is irrelevant.